# How to easily know where a function is defined or implemented in Chrome dev tools? Function is used in an AngularJS attribute

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

If I have an AngularJS app and I see this `<li ng-show="vm.CanUse('a-b-c')" ng-class..` in the Elements tab in Chrome dev tools, is there a way to quickly and easily navigate to where the CanUse function is defined?

I know I can do a search with ctrl-shift-F in the Source tab but if I have a ton of files which use the function or have multiple implementations with the same name, it can take me a while to find the implementation I want.

I tried something like this: `<li ng-show="debugger;vm.CanUse('a-b-c')" ng-class..` expecting to break into the debugger but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you just add "debugger;" to the top of each definition of CanUse() in the source (probably you are aware of this)? But no, the use of "debugger" inline the expression won't work as this is limited javascript.

Comment: Well.. if I knew which file it is I wouldn't need this question. I could have just put a breakpoint in each of those files where CanUse is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special AngularJS debug extension called Batarang for this type of scope level debugging.  However, it requires a plugin.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Once you are in "elements" pane, click the function definition. Next, click $scope tab. Then "show function definition". See image below.

From there you should be able to click a "blue breakpoint" (left margin, near line number) for debugging.

Execute the function (clicking button etc) and the debugger should stop at that function.

[image]